# Uniformly distributed random point inside a frustum

Tags: random, 3d, polygon

I have a 3D scene and I want "litter" it with X number of objects placed randomly within the viewing frustum.

I tried using 3 randoms: **X** + **Y** (viewport 0..1), and then **Z** distance from camera and then projecting using the camera distance. However this doesn't yield a uniform distribution and there are too many objects close to the camera and too few further away.

There is the option of generating a random point within the cube and filtering those points that are outside the view frustum, but I'm generating a shitload of these and I'm worried about performance.

How can I generate a random point inside a frustum in a uniformly distributed manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on gamedev.net in an old forum post:

[http://www.gamedev.net/topic/254550-geometryrandomnessuniform-filling/page_*p*_2539021_*hl*_+random%20+frustum#entry2539021](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/254550-geometryrandomnessuniform-filling/page__p__2539021__hl__+random%20+frustum#entry2539021)

Answer (score 2):

This is just nicely formatted code from the final solution in the link in [Amir Abiri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/800334/amir-abiri)'s answer, since the code in the link has abysmal formatting quality.

In java, since that's what I'm using it in, and with some variable name changes (also, tests passed; it works nicely)

Note that this can be made nicer in several ways depending on the application (eg. as was mentioned in the linked site from [Amir Abiri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/800334/amir-abiri)'s answer, some variables could be calculated once and used multiple times so long as the same frustum is being used)

```
public static final double ONE_THIRD = 1d / 3, EPSILON = 0.0000001;

public static double getUniformRandZInFrustum(Random random, double nearW, double nearH, double farW, double farH, double depth)
{
    double a = (farW - nearW) * (farH - nearH) / (depth * depth);
    double b = (nearH * (farW - nearW) + nearW * (farH - nearH)) / depth;

    if (Math.abs(a) < EPSILON)
    {
        if (Math.abs(b) < EPSILON)
        {
            //Rectangular prism
            return (random.nextDouble(depth));
        }

        //Trapezoidal prism
        double c = nearW * nearH;
        double area = depth * (c + depth * 0.5 * b);
        double r = random.nextDouble(area);
        return (-c + Math.sqrt(c * c + 2 * b * r)) / b;
    }

    //General case
    double c = nearW * nearH;
    double area = depth * (c + depth * (0.5 * b + depth * ONE_THIRD * a));
    double r = random.nextDouble(area);
    double det = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    double part1 = b * (b * b - 6 * a * c) - 12 * a * a * r;
    double part2 = Math.sqrt(part1 * part1 - det * det * det);
    if (part1 < 0.0) part2 = -part2;
    double part3 = part1 + part2;
    if (part3 < 0.0) part3 = -Math.pow(-part3, ONE_THIRD);
    else part3 = Math.pow(part3, ONE_THIRD);
    return -(b + det / part3 + part3) / (2 * a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Distribute the points in NDC space and back project them with an inverse frustum transformation and w-divide into view space.

Comment: I'm sorry you lost me... I understand the clip space part and the back projection, however if I'm not mistaken so far that would yield a non-uniform result? I don't understand what you mean by w-divide into view space?

Comment: @AmirAbiri: Look at the typical transformation pipeline. First you multiply view space coordinates with the projection matrix P: `r_clip = P * r`, and then, to introduce the perspective effect the w divide is applied to reach NDC `r_NDC.{x,y,z,w} = r_clip.{x,y,z,w} / r_clip.w`. You've to go the exact opposite direction. I recommend taking a look at the sourcecode of `gluUnProject` (you can find it in the Mesa3D sources).

Comment: So if I understand correctly, we'd be essentially picking random points in {0..1, 0..1, 0..1} where X and Y represent the normalized screen coordinates and the Z component is the normalized distance between the near clip and the far clip, and then reverse-project this back to world coordinates?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but that wouldn't yield a uniform distribution inside the resulting frustum? There should be less chance for an object to appear at z=0 then at z=h.

Comment: @AmirAbiri: Indeed the density of points gets higher for objects farther away from your near clipping plane. Which is exactly what you want, because you were complaining about "too much objects close to the camers".

Comment: No what I mean is that I don't see how the solution you are describing will yield a uniform distribution. The correct solution should give **more** probability for a point in z=h to be picked than a point in z=0. The solution you are describing is identical to what I am already doing.